# SHFileOperation cannot remove folder

Tags: c++, wix

I am writing a C++ Custom action for WiX that will be called during installation to remove any leftovers installed by the installer. Consider the following code:

```
UINT __stdcall DeleteResidue(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    UINT er = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    LPWSTR lpFolderPath = NULL;
    std::wstring temp;
    SHFILEOPSTRUCT shFile;

    hr = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "DeleteResidue");
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to initialize");

    hr = WcaGetProperty(L"LPCOMMAPPDATAFOLDER",&lpFolderPath);
    ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failure in Finding Common App Data Folder");

    temp = std::wstring(lpFolderPath);
    temp+=L"\0\0";

    //Stop the LPA and LPA Monitor Service. Then delete the residue.
    WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Doing Delete Residue");

    ZeroMemory(&shFile, sizeof(shFile));
    shFile.hwnd = NULL;
    shFile.wFunc = FO_DELETE;
    shFile.pFrom = temp.c_str();
    shFile.fFlags = FOF_ALLOWUNDO | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOERRORUI;
    BOOL res = DirectoryExists(lpFolderPath);
    if(res)
    {
        WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "The directory exist");
        int result = SHFileOperation(&shFile);
        if(!result)
            WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "The directory should have deleted by now");
        else
            WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "The directory could not be deleted.Error code %d", result);
    }       
    else
    {
        WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "It Seems the Installed Folder is No more there");
    }



LExit:
    er = SUCCEEDED(hr) ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
    return WcaFinalize(er);
}
```

In above code, we get `C:\ProgramData` in`LPCOMMAPPDATAFOLDER`. The doc states that `pFrom` should be `double null terminated`. However the return value of the code is `0x2` i.e. `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. What is wrong in the code above?

Comment: I should point out that if you are literally installing some files directly from the MSI file (you added them to the MSI build) into the the common appdata folder and then you are deleting them, then a repair will simply bring them back, asking for the MSI file so they can be reinstalled. This might happen when a shortcut is used, or right-click the MSI file and choose Repair and see if they just get reinstalled.

Comment: The installer will install the files into `ProgramFiles` or `ProgramFiles(x86)` depending upon OS. Anything the program will output are written in `CommonAppDataFolder`. Isn't this the common pattern in installer?

Comment: A post-install removal of files that were installed from the MSI's File table will result in their restoration with a repair, either right-click the MSI or aitomatically. If you are removing files created by the app, or by custom actions then yes there will be no repair.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not double nul terminating the `pFrom`.

You have a standard string (which includes the null terminator when you call `.c_str()` on it).

```
temp = std::wstring(lpFolderPath);
```

You then concatenate an empty string onto it:

```
temp+=L"\0\0";
```

This leaves the original string unchanged. This is because the `std::string::operator+(const wchar_t*)` takes a null terminated string. The fact that you have 2 nulls is immaterial it only reads up to the first null. It doesn't even add that null as what you've effectively given it is an empty string and the result of concatenating an empty string to something else is a no-op.

There's a few ways to solve this, but probably easiest is to change

```
temp+=L"\0\0";
```

to

```
temp.push_back(L'\0');
```

which explicitly adds another nul to the string so when you eventaully call  `temp.c_str()` you'll get back the double nul-terminated string you need.